# Проблемы настройки Ubuntu+postfix+dovecot. 550 5.7.1 relaying denied

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

Поднял с помощью многочисленных руководств в гугле ubuntu+postfix+dovecot. Вроде как все работает - порты pop3, imap, smtp открыты, сообщений об ошибках в логах нет. Но при попытке отправить письмо с внешнего ресурса (gmail, например), письмо возвращается с отметкой <mail@###.ru>: host rx2.sparkpostmail.com[44.240.8.72] said: 550 5.7.1    relaying denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)
И при этом ни в каких логах ни слова нет о том, что ко мне кто-нибудь стучался.
Что это может быть? Уже не знаю, куда копать - двое суток сижу))
Не знаю, какие конфиги нужно показать - их много и они длинные))